# jQuery Dom Manipulation : Adding wrapper div around a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation

> when I'm designing a website I came across this issue . I had to
>   create a wrapper DIV around a DIV  in my html code. So I'm asking this
>   Question because this will be useful to others in future

**I wan't to add a wrapper div to this div using jQuery**

```
<div class="innerdiv"></div>
```

Comment: rtm http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: obviously didn't attempt any research on this ... a search for "wrap element jQuery" or similar should have turned up just what you needed

Comment: @charlietfl do you think this question is unnecessary ?

Comment: I just think it is lazy. Basic research is expected before asking questions here. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can wrap a div with another div using jQuery **.wrap()**

```
<div class="innerdiv"></div>
```

in the jQuery code you have to select the innerdiv and then you have to create the wrapper div insdie the **wrap()** . and you need to import jQuery to run this.

```
 $( ".innerdiv" ).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
```

[checkout my codepen link here](http://codepen.io/feizel/pen/ZLVELL)

Comment: Why are you answering this yourself when there are already 2 other answers showing the same method??

Comment: @charlietfl check my question again. i wanted to help others who is luking for same issue as i faced hope you understand

Comment: But that's like saying the other people who answered did so for no good reason. Why should they bother if you are simply going to use their answers to copy to your own?

Answer (score 1):

This has probably been asked and answered, but here is my response:

First, see [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Second, here is the simple answer:

`$( ".innerdiv" ).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides a method for you:

```
$('.innerdiv').wrap('<div class="outerdiv"></div>');
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: LOL, I think we responded at about the same time as one another. Good job!